# Unable to create a new instance of 'org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver'

Tags: spring, jsf

I am integrating spring with jsf but I am getting this exception at runtime. 
This is the code for my faces-config.xml file. The spring version I am using is 5.0.0.

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.mkyong.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>userBo</property-name>
        <value>#{userBo}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: This is the schema:
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver from [Module "deployment.NewProject1.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: Do you have spring-web as dependency?

Comment: Yes spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: I can even import this class in a normal java source file. I guess what is the problem with faces-config.xml

Comment: You can edit your question and add relevant info there instead of in comments! And I would start by using a more modern tutorial... By using CDI annotations, you can use SpringBeans without any config/hassle afaik...